# VisualForce/APEX Chart's bar with Redirecting URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, url

It's possible to add redirecting URL's to other Visual Force Pages by clicking on the chart bars?How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `"<a>"` html element inside `<apex:chart>` tag and make it invisible. You will probably need some CSS style to place the html element wherever you want. See attached screenshots.

Hope this will help you.

**VF Page**

[image: VF page]

**Result**
[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it helps. The problem is that, if you want to cover only one bar(for example) with the <a> element and use it in several bars, you have to put it by a fixed-way. If you open a sub-menu on the left, the <a> mismatch its bar. I'm searching a way that all covered area of the bar (or peace of pie chart, whatelse) could have a redirecting link to another URL, dynamically. But i'm not sure that could be possible.

Comment: You can use JavaScript tricks to solve your problem. Use firebug to find it out. Also, you can add "onclick" attribute to "<div>" element that renders <apex:chart node.